# How to use rule templates in Kie Workbench?

Tags: drools, kie-workbench, drools-kie-server

I have installled and have deployed a few rules files to kie server using drools workbench. But now I want to use template files to be used and create drl files out it and then deploy those rules witk kie workbench. I have found an option to add template file such as Guided Rule Template. But the source cannot be edited. Usually when we define templates files we start with a `template header`. A sample template file is shown below.

```
template header
    frequency
    memory
    power

package com.myspace.test;

import com.myspace.test.GPU;

template "power-for-gpu"

rule "Choice recommended power supply for GPU_@{row.rowNumber}"

when
    $gpu : GPU(frequency ==@{frequency}, memory== @{memory})
then
    $gpu.setPower(@{power})
end

end template
```

but the Guided Rule Template doesn't seems to be in the above manner. It starts with `package` and no `template header` can be found or created default. There is no option for defining variables. Its generated source looks like rule file and not template. Is there anyway to define and use templates in kie workbench.

Comment: Did you get a solution to your question. If yes please reply here.

Comment: @AkhilkumarAmarneni As far as I understood kie workbench doesn't support the template as we do access in java. If you would like to checkout an example of how to do it in java see my repo here https://github.com/vishnu-chalil/drools-template. If you insist on using kie workbench you would have to use templates in the format kie work bench supports as far as I understood.